# What's the most efficient way to check whether two long values (in millis) belong to the same second

Tags: java, time, compare

Currently I'm using `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(valueInMillis)` to check whether two millisecond values come from the same second. Can you recommend a faster algo for this operation?

Thanks.

Comment: The maximum difference between the values will be a couple of days. Hope this makes the question clearer. ;)

Comment: Please describe what "from the same second" means.

Comment: Why do you think, you have a performance issue? The code used is just a simple devide.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I will be receiving possibly hundreds of data in a short span of time and would only like to keep track of the most recent value per second interval.

@Arne, I understand this is a simple divide but I'm running out of ideas on how to save up some processing time and thought this might be worth a shot. ;) Plus this operation will be performed several hundred times per second so a little savings could certainly help.

Comment: I believe if you describe what you mean with "from the same second" you have your algorithm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code behind `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSecond(long d)`:

```
public long toSeconds(long d) { return d/(C3/C2); }
```

where `C2`,`C3` are static constants. You can save a single division... In that case, I preferred your actual code, it's easier to understand

Comment: If C2 and C3 are constants, the _compiler_ calculates the result of C3/C2 and uses that.

Comment: Even better ;) Then it's *as fast as possible*

Answer (score 5):

Divide each by 1000.  Since they are integers/longs, the decimal will be truncated.  If they are in the same seconds, the values will be the same.

Comment: ... unless he needs to get rid of the rest of the date as well (from year down to minute), the question leaves room for interpretation ;)

Comment: I need to check whether they are from the same year/month/date/hour/minute/second. ;)

Comment: If one doesn't care about the year/month/date, the upper values can be removed via modulus first

Answer (score 1):

Assuming t1 and t2 are time stamps. Eg from System.currentTimeMillis()

```
public static boolean isSameSecond(long t1, long t2){
  return (t1/1000) == (t2/1000)
}
```